# How do I printout my 2 dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, sudoku

Trying to build a data structure for a sudoku board, and I want to print it to the console for starters. I'm using a 2 dimensional array for represent each cell on a sudoku game and I'm having a really nooby problem printing it out.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] puzzleBoard = {};

    //Row 1
    puzzleBoard[1][1] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[2][1] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[3][1] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[4][1] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[5][1] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[6][1] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[7][1] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[8][1] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[9][1] = 0;

    //Row 2
    puzzleBoard[1][2] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[2][2] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[3][2] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[4][2] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[5][2] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[6][2] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[7][2] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[8][2] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[9][2] = 0;

    //Row 3
    puzzleBoard[1][3] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[2][3] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[3][3] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[4][3] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[5][3] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[6][3] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[7][3] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[8][3] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[9][3] = 0;

    //Row 4
    puzzleBoard[1][4] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[2][4] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[3][4] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[4][4] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[5][4] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[6][4] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[7][4] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[8][4] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[9][4] = 0;

    //Row 5
    puzzleBoard[1][5] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[2][5] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[3][5] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[4][5] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[5][5] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[6][5] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[7][5] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[8][5] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[9][5] = 0;

    //Row 6
    puzzleBoard[1][6] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[2][6] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[3][6] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[4][6] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[5][6] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[6][6] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[7][6] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[8][6] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[9][6] = 0;

    //Row 7
    puzzleBoard[1][7] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[2][7] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[3][7] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[4][7] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[5][7] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[6][7] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[7][7] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[8][7] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[9][7] = 0;

    //Row 8
    puzzleBoard[1][8] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[2][8] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[3][8] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[4][8] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[5][8] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[6][8] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[7][8] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[8][8] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[9][8] = 0;

    //Row 9
    puzzleBoard[1][9] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[2][9] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[3][9] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[4][9] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[5][9] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[6][9] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[7][9] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[8][9] = 0;
    puzzleBoard[9][9] = 0;

    int rows = 9;
    int columns = 9;

    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i < rows; i++){
        for(j = 1; j < columns; j++){
            System.out.print(puzzleBoard[i][j] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println( "" );
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify a size for your array.

`int[][] puzzleBoard = {};` should be `int[][] puzzleBoard = new int[10][10];`

There is no need to initialize your array with a for loop or line by line if you're only filling it with 0.

Then arrays are 0 base indexed. So the first element will be at position `[0][0]` and the last one at position `[9][9]`.

You could also remove your two variables `rows` and `columns`.

Finally, you should modify your for loop to start from 0.

```
for (i = 0; i < puzzleBoard.length; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < puzzleBoard[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(puzzleBoard[i][j] + " ");    
        }
        System.out.println( "" );
    }
```

To learn more about arrays in Java, I advise you to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize the array elements with a for loop as well!

Also, remember, Java arrays are zero based, so the topmost cell would be `puzzleboard[0][0]`!

You should also specify a size for your array - `int[][] puzzleBoard = new int[10][10];`

Comment: oh yes, and as said in the other answer, initialize counter in for loop with 0!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `java.util.Arrays.deepToString()` to print 2D arrays:

> Returns a string representation of the "deep contents" of the
>   specified array. If the array contains other arrays as elements, the
>   string representation contains their contents and so on. This method
>   is designed for converting multidimensional arrays to strings.
>
> The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements,
>   enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by
>   the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space). Elements are
>   converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object), unless they are
>   themselves arrays.